# Передача параметра из вызыванной в вызывающую страницу

Tags: php

Такая ситуация: в одном файле у меня идет подключение к базе. Но ее я этот файл вызываю через другой файл. ... и хотелось из вызванного файла передать обратно в вызывающий файл параметр (`true` или `false` типа подключение прошло успешно или нет).
Как реализовать

### файл1 вызыванный db.php

```
<code>
<?php
     // Выполняем все команды файла config.php
     include ('config.php');
     // Пытаемся соединиться с сервером базы данных MySQL
     $db = mysql_connect($sdb_name,$user_name,$user_password);
     $stat_db = 1; //переменная для определения возможности подключения к базе по умолчанию 1 - true
     $stat_tb = 1; //переменная для определния возмож подключения к таблицы
     //Проверяем, удачно ли прошло подключение
     if(!$db)
     {
     echo( '<center--><p><b>Невозможно подключиться к серверу базы данных !</b></p>');
     $stat_db = 0;
     exit();
     }

     //Проверяем доступность нужной БД
     if(!@mysql_select_db($db_name,$db))
     {
     echo( '<center><p><b>База данных '.$db_name.' недоступна!</b></p></center>');
     $stat_tb = 0;
     exit();
     }
     //Вывод сообщения об удачном выполнении подключения
     //Строку расположенную ниже после отладки - удалить
     echo( '<center><p><b>Подключение к базе данных '.$db_name.' выполнено.</b></p></center>');
 ?>
</code>
```

### Файл 2, вызывающий index.php

```
<?
  include ('db.php');
   echo $stat_db;
  if  ($_POST[$stat_db]=0)
   {
      echo 'Базы не существует';
   }

?>
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/language.variables.scope.php

Answer (score 1):

1. Как писал [@Равнодушный](/users/8603/%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%88%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9), все ваши переменные в первом файле будут видны во втором. Т.е. в `index.php` вы можете использовать и `$stat_tb`, и `$stat_tb`.
2. Вы можете использовать конструкцию вида

   ```
   $has_conneciton = include('db.php')
   ```

   А в самом `db.php` в конце поставить

   ```
   return true; //для удачного подключения, или же false для неудачного
   ```
3. Что вы хотели сказать этой строкой, для меня осталось загадкой...

   ```
   if  ($_POST[$stat_db]=0)
   ```